# openCV center of image rotation in C

Tags: c, image, opencv, rotation

I want to rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise, but it seems the rotation point is wrong. How do I find the rotation center of the source image?

```
    img=cvLoadImage(argv[1],-1); 
height    = img->height;
width     = img->width;
step      = img->widthStep;
channels  = img->nChannels;
data      = (uchar *)img->imageData;

    IplImage *rotatedImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(height,width), IPL_DEPTH_8U,img->nChannels);

    CvPoint2D32f center;
    center.x = width/2;
    center.y = height/2;
    CvMat *mapMatrix = cvCreateMat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );

    cv2DRotationMatrix(center, 90, 1.0, mapMatrix);
    cvWarpAffine(img, rotatedImg, mapMatrix, CV_INTER_LINEAR + CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0));


cvShowImage("My image", rotatedImg );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the translation parameters of the affine transformation matrix.

To rotate the image by 90 degrees and fit the output in the destination image, you can do the following:

```
IplImage *rotatedImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(height,width), IPL_DEPTH_8U,img->nChannels);

CvPoint2D32f center;
center.x = width/2.0f;
center.y = height/2.0f;
CvMat *mapMatrix = cvCreateMat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );

float x = width - 1.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

cv2DRotationMatrix(center, 90, 1, mapMatrix);
cvmSet(mapMatrix,0,2,y);
cvmSet(mapMatrix,1,2,x);
cvWarpAffine(img, rotatedImg, mapMatrix, CV_INTER_LINEAR + CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0));
```

Note the offset values x and y. These values adjust the result according to the output image size.

**P.S:**
This is not a generic solution. It is only for rotation of 90 degrees.